# How can I write streaming Dataflow pipelines that support schema evolution?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building some data streaming pipelines that read from Kafka and write to various sinks using Google Cloud Dataflow. The pipeline looks something like this (simplified).

```
// Example pipeline that writes to BigQuery.
Pipeline.create(options)
    .apply(KafkaIO.read().withTopic(options.topic))
    .apply(/* Convert to a Row type */)
    .setRowSchema(schemaRegistry.lookup(options.topic))
    .apply(
        BigQueryIO.write<Row>()
            .useBeamSchema()
            .withCreateDisposition(CreateDispotion.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withProject(options.outputProject)
            .withDataset(options.outputDataset)
            .withTable(options.outputTable)
    )
```

I plan to run a pipeline for each of our Kafka topics, of which there are hundreds. The pipeline looks up the schema for the given topic during the planning stage. This allows `BigQueryIO` to create the necessary tables before starting the pipeline.

**Question:** How can I support evolving schemas in my Dataflow pipelines?

I've explored the option of updating an existing Dataflow job (using the `--update` flag). The thought is that I could automate the process of submitting an updated job whenever a schema changes. But updating a job seems to incur about 3 minutes of downtime. For some of the jobs, that much downtime won't work. I'm looking for other solutions that hopefully have no more than a few seconds of downtime.

Comment: You might ask in dev@beam.apache.org for your question. There you could get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask in there as well.

Comment: a possible solution would be to use protobuf schema, you may refer to the following blog post [part1](https://robertsahlin.com/schema-evolution-in-streaming-dataflow-jobs-and-bigquery-tables-part-1/),[part2](https://robertsahlin.com/schema-evolution-in-streaming-dataflow-jobs-and-bigquery-tables-part-2/).

Comment: @Abdelilah.F And part 3 here: https://robertsahlin.com/schema-evolution-in-streaming-dataflow-jobs-and-bigquery-tables-part-3/

Comment: We have an external json file that represents the schema, we watch for changes in DF and if there is a change we apply the change in BQ schema:              ```bqTable.updateSchema(Schema.of(newFieldList));```

Comment: @JamesHall: Hi, did you find a solution to this ? If yes, glad if you can share ! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no, I abandoned this project.